# How add an public API to an intranet-like site?

Tags: django, pinax

I run a Pinax-site for collaborative purposes. I added 'account.middleware.AuthenticatedMiddleware' to 'MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES' in order to not allow anonymous access to anything on the site.

But now I need public APIs to be enabled. Is there any solutions besides adding 'login_required'-decorator at all the views that still need to be private?

**edit**
Gregor Müllegger answer doesn't work. settings.AUTHENTICATED_EXEMPT_URLS seems to get overwritten somewhere in the code

```
class AuthenticatedMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, login_url=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME):
        if login_url is None:
            login_url = settings.LOGIN_URL
        self.redirect_field_name = redirect_field_name
        self.login_url = login_url
        self.exemptions = [
            r"^%s" % settings.MEDIA_URL,
            r"^%s" % settings.STATIC_URL,
            r"^%s$" % login_url,
        ] 
        print "settings.AUTHENTICATED_EXEMPT_URLS ",settings.AUTHENTICATED_EXEMPT_URLS
        if ( settings.AUTHENTICATED_EXEMPT_URLS):
            self.exemptions += settings.AUTHENTICATED_EXEMPT_URLS


print "settings.AUTHENTICATED_EXEMPT_URLS ",settings.AUTHENTICATED_EXEMPT_URLS
```

doesn't print my settings but this:

```
settings.AUTHENTICATED_EXEMPT_URLS  ['^/account/signup/$', '^/account/password_reset', '^/account/confirm_email', '^/openid']
```

I will try to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [source code of `AuthenticatedMiddleware`](http://github.com/pinax/pinax/blob/ddfd4b8cac714ffc30c73604e5399860210054f0/pinax/apps/account/middleware.py).

It reveals that there is a setting called `AUTHENTICATED_EXEMPT_URLS`. It can contain regular expressions that are left public. Set it to something like this in your `settings.py`:

```
AUTHENTICATED_EXEMPT_URLS = (r"^api/",)
```

This will make any URLs below `/api/` available without being logged in.t

Comment: The urls in `AUTHENTICATED_EXEMPT_URLS` you described above are defined in the default settings of the `intranet_project` (see this please: http://github.com/pinax/pinax/blob/ddfd4b8cac714ffc30c73604e5399860210054f0/pinax/projects/intranet_project/settings.py#L199 ). You can append your urls (like `r'api/'`) to it. *(Tip: I often search the whole code base of my projects to find such redefinitions with `grep -r` or something similiar. This helps out most of the time)*

Comment: I dont think, overwriting the default-blueprint is useful, as it breaks updatecycles. Instead I altered `exemptions` in `<my_project>/apps/account/middleware.py`